# How to store config data to stm32f103C8t6 flash?

Tags: stm32

I would like to store my configuration data to flash so it stays permanent after reboot.I am using CooCox CoIDE for development but unable to find any example on how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use STM32 EEPROM emulation driver to use few pages of your flash as an EEPROM. More details can be found in any of their application notes/datasheets. You may find the driver [here](http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/tools/PF257846).